# Special character in program

Tags: .net, vb.net

Today my client just input '&' symbol into the text box. The string was something like 'ABC & XYZ'. When my program read the string, it interpret the symbol & as a parameter therefore prompt an error something like 'parameters out of bound'. I already explain to them that there are some special characters that needed to avoid using.

So I would like to know where can I look for a set of special characters that are not able to input into text box to avoid confusion in the program? Any links to this matter would help.

Comment: Huh?...sounds more like you didn't write very good code to parse the data in the TextBox.  Show us your code...

Comment: show us the code that consume that textbox

Comment: Your code is responsible to handle any input in the proper manner. Show us the code so that we can comment more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters to avoid pretty much depends on the Database and Programming Language.

In VB, what I watch out for mostly is on the use of a Double Quote(") which will terminate your string in VB.

If you have SQL Server/Mysql/MSACCESS as a database the Single Quote (') which terminates the string in SQL should also be avoided.  Also the Dash(-) for turning the command into a comment. Since we're talking about comments, (/*) should also be wary of.

As for preventive measures, there's a plethora of them

1.) Parse the string before passing it.

2.) use Stored procedures in databases

3.) Manipulate keypress events (not really what I'd recommend, but it's a solution)

**Edit**: also, be wary of input that needs to be numeric! If you type in a string where a number is needed a database might read it as an object within it. This is easily prevented with the use of the val() function in vb.net

**EDIT 2** you could use REPLACE.

```
        dim x as string = "This is Original"
        x = x.replace("Original", "Replaced")
        'you can also do x = replace(x, "Original", "Replaced")
        msgbox(x)
```

you should now have the string "This is Replaced"

Comment: How do I parse string? Is it something like textbox1.text.tostring()?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, friend. You can use the Replace function in .net. See my comment, friend.

Comment: Okay let says I want to prevent user from input special characters that ONLY reserved by Oracle database and .Net. Is there a list of them? Therefore I shall replace all of them with a space.

Comment: Please try the following link for ORACLE: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm

Comment: Based on experience for .NET, just find a way to replace or filter the doublequote character ("). You can do this via REPLACE("""", "the replacement")

Comment: Thanks alot Malky Kid. Besides this, I also need to parse parameter to the stored procedure. But I guess I will just figure this out myself. Appreciated your effort.